# checking which service did outbound connection

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using EKS and one node did one outbound connection which was unusual. Because of that AWS GuardDuty got triggered.

Now I want to find out which process on that node (EC2) did that connection?

I just want to make sure that this node is compromised to not.

I don't know that connection started from a pod or machine.

### I tried

- If some pod is doing it then now we can't guarantee that the same pods are on that node.
- currently, that connection is not active. I checked.

Comment: Do you have an IP? with EKS all pods get a real IP in VPC.

Comment: Don't know if it started from the pod or from the machine itself. GuardDuty is giving only instance IP.